# How to get execution time from Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run

We recently switched from Google Functions to running those functions in Google Cloud Run. One metric we noticed missing is execution time of the function. You can see executions per second and execution latency, but not the time it took for the function to run.

The question is, how to setup an execution time metric for Cloud Run?

We noticed that there is a response time for each function call in stack driver, does this correlate accurately with the functions execution time? If so this value could be saved and used, though we haven't been able to verify. Please advise.

Comment: Do you want a metric per entry point of your service?

Comment: Yes, @guillaumeblaquiere, I would like a metric per each service name

Comment: Thanks for the precision, and sorry for my bad english. My question was; do you need a metric per `path`. I mean a metric for `https://myservice/cart` and another one for `https://myservice/order`. If no, Steren answer is the right one.

Answer (score 3):

The [request_latencies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-run) metric is an equivalent to function execution time. It measures the time between which each request was received and returned.

Comment: There isn't a definition for "request latencies" in the link you provided. How is request latency correlate with response time? I am not understanding how a request latency functionally is equivalent to execution time. Is there some detail which could be added to it's calculation, etc.?

Comment: From my understanding, with function, you process only 1 request at the same time. 1 request = 1 Function execution -> It's the processing time of your request. With Cloud Run, the execution time means nothing because it can handle several requests in the same time. The request latency is the processing time of your request.